# Functional test with Codeception and 3rd party REST API

Tags: php, rest, testing, codeception

I am using the functional tests of Codeception to test the routes of my REST application. In a few of my routes I use a third party REST API to get some data. To speak with this third party API I use a composer package published by the same party. Normally you would use a http mocker to fake the API calls to test it. The problem is that the domains are hardcoded in the composer package, so that I can't change them with a environment variable.

How could I go about testing my routes without using the real API calls?

Comment: it's a functional test, isn't this the point? You are supposed to test real functionality!

Comment: The API needs authentication with registered accounts. I don't really want to use this one. I just want to make sure my application works.   
Dou you have some example code for this?

Comment: if you can set environment in your app, you could reconfigure it to use a mock which returns fake data

Comment: A mock of the composer package? How exactly could I create the mock and where?

Comment: not the package, but the class that you call. if they see it's the test environment, you could create a phpunit mock object, replace the original,  and when you call `randomMethodThatCallsApi()` get it to return some json or whatever, copy it from the real call

Comment: So I should put the code to write the phpunit mock inside my normal application and only call it when a specific env variable is set for testing?

Comment: yes, although it seems a bit odd, it's the only way you could get the app to run normally but use the mocked api. it does mean phpunit would be a required package and not a dev-require though

Comment: Yeah...I really don't like that :D